# Flutter. How to change the styles dynamically

Tags: flutter

Hello I'm new using Flutter and my English it's very bad, but I need help about change dynamically the style of the Widgets

For example, I want to change the text color according to the value returned by a JSON field.
In this example, the text is amberAccent[400], but depends on results returned by a JSON field I want to change to other

Can I do an if sentence?
How?
Thank you

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    this.setState(() {
      data = JSON.decode(response.body);
    });
    print(data[1]["title"]);

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Listviews"),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new MyCard(
            title: new Text(data[index]["title"],
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,color: Colors.amberAccent[400]
                ),),
            subtitle: new Text(data[index]["body"],
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 10.0,color: Colors.pinkAccent[200]))
          );
//          return new Card(
//            child: new Text(data[index]["title"]),
//          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  MyCard({this.title, this.subtitle});

  final Widget title;
  final Widget subtitle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
        child: new Card(
            child: new Container(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[this.title, this.subtitle]))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a theme like shown in https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/themes/

> ```
> new Theme(
>   // Create a unique theme with "new ThemeData"
>   data: new ThemeData(
>     accentColor: Colors.yellow,
>   ),
>   child: new FloatingActionButton(
>     onPressed: () {},
>     child: new Icon(Icons.add),
>   ),
> );
> ```

or in your example `accentColor: Colors.amberAccent[400]`

to get a value from a theme

> ```
> new Container(
>   color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
>   child: new Text(
>     'Text with a background color',
>     style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
>   ),
> );
> ```

You can combine this with a `StreamBuilder' or`FutureBuilder` to update theme data.

You can also build your custom `Theme` and `ThemeData` classes for properties that are not covered by the classes provided by Flutter.